# How to compare excel file to SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

What I am trying to achieve is to take an excel file, upload it and check the data in the excel file then compare it with what data is in the SQL table.

So for example in my excel file I have 1 column named "DeviceName"

```
DeviceName
----------
Desktop 1
Desktop 2
Desktop 3
Desktop 4
Desktop 5
Desktop 6
Desktop 7
```

Then in my SQL table "tbl.Devices" I have several columns:

```
Id  | Name  | Status  | DeviceName |
------------------------------------
1   | Jo    | Active  | Desktop 1  |
2   | Jhon  | Active  | Desktop 2  |
3   | Sara  | Active  | Desktop 3  |
4   | Sam   | Active  | Desktop 4  |
```

So what needs to happen is when uploading the excel file it then needs to check column "DeviceName" in the SQL table then compare it with the data in the "DeviceName" column of the excel file and then add a new column named "ComparedData", or create a new table for example:

```
Id  | Name  | Status  | DeviceName | ComparedData  |
----------------------------------------------------
1   | Jo    | Active  | Desktop 1  | Desktop 1     |
2   | John  | Active  | Desktop 2  | Desktop 2     |
3   | Sara  | Active  | Desktop 3  | Desktop 3     |
4   | Sam   | Active  | Desktop 4  | Desktop 4     |
```

Then if possible create an separate Excel file with the text that has no comparison to the SQL table, for example:

```
DeviceName
----------
Desktop 5
Desktop 6
Desktop 7
```

So this will assist me in filtering devices that are no longer active or required and then can be removed.

**UPDATE**

This is what I am working on now:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": 
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": 
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;

    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();


        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OfficeConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblReport";

                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CompareData", "CompareData");
                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when testing I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The given ColumnName 'DeviceName' does not match up with any column in data source.'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I figured out what I was doing wrong (Thanks to @ChrisBD)
The code now runs fine but when examining the SQL table I get this:

```
Id  | Name  | Status  | DeviceName | ComparedData  |
----------------------------------------------------
1   | Jo    | Active  | Desktop 1  | Null          |
2   | John  | Active  | Desktop 2  | Null          |
3   | Sara  | Active  | Desktop 3  | Null          |
4   | Sam   | Active  | Desktop 4  | Null          |
5   | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 1     |
6   | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 2     |
7   | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 3     |
8   | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 4     |
9   | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 5     |
10  | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 6     |
11  | Null  | Null    | Null       | Desktop 7     |
```

Its adding it to the table but not next to the original row (or Id)
and also does not remove the ones as described above

Comment: First need to read the excel record and bind that into a list, then need to compare that list with your `database device list`

Comment: I wonder what is the exact problem. Reading an excel using c#? Looking data from a database? Removing the common items on two lists? Writing an excel file?

Comment: @Cleptus There is no problem, I need some assistance on how to achieve the above?

Comment: Which bit precisely? We'd like to help, but Stack Overflow isn't a generic code writing service. What have you tried? Have you written any code to read an excel file or to retrieve data from your SQL database?

Comment: @ChrisBD I have just tried some code but not doing what I need it to do.  Will update my question now.

Comment: @Kieth Thank you, that gives people something to help you with.  Always best to place DB access within `try ... catch` blocks as it helps with faults like this. Explicit db connection `Close()` not required within `using` blocks. I would rename the excel column header, say "Device_name" so that we know if the issue is with excel or sql access. Have you pinpointed the line that throws the exception? I would also suggest running the excel and sql access in separate blocks

Comment: @ChrisBD No worries,  Thanks for your suggestion will implement that now but have updated my question with the issue I am sitting now.  I will implement the `try ... catch` now.

Answer (score 1):

If this was a one-time (or rare use only) scenario, I would be tempted to simply write a parser which checks each row of the Excel document and calls a stored procedure to see if that device exists in the table, and if not, add it to a different table. If it was a page that will be used many times and needs to be performant, there is a nuGet package for `ExcelDataReader` which massively simplifies converting Excel documents to dataTables.

Using the `ExcelDataReader` and `ExcelDataReaderDataSet` Nuget packages, I threw together the following in a few minutes:

```
// set file location and name
string fileLOC = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

// save the Excel doc to server loc
fileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileLOC);

// open it in ExcelDataReader
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLOC, FileMode.Open);
IExcelDataReader reader =  ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fs);
DataSet ds = reader.AsDataSet();

// Create datatable 
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
reader.Close();

// Remove file from server
System.IO.File.Delete(fileLOC);

// iterate over datatable of devices
foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
{
        string DeviceName = drow[0].ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("check_device", [YOUR SQL CONNECTION]);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceName", DeviceName);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

The `check_device` stored procedure:

```
create procedure check_device
(
    @deviceName nvarchar(50)
)
as
if exists(select id from Devices where [DeviceName] = @deviceName and [Status] = 'Active')
begin
update Devices set [ComparedDevice] = @deviceName where DeviceName = @deviceName
end
else
begin
insert into dbo.Unused_Devices
(
    DeviceName
)
values
(
    @deviceName
)
end
```

When I run this code on a button click, it updates the Device table
to set the comparedDevice field to the one found. If not found, it places that device into the Unused_Devices table.

Like I mentioned, I wouldn't use this if the page was hit many times, but for a rare-use or just one-off its fine.